# Solaris C++ program crash. Help on mdb debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, unix, segmentation-fault, solaris

I'm trying to debug a segmentation fault using mdb in solaris (as this is the only available option for me). The following is the core dump

```
`threading model: multi-threaded
status: process terminated by SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault)
C++ symbol demangling enabled
librax.so void RajHistory_Backend::addMessage+0x58()
librax.sovoid RajErrorSink::output+0xe0() 
librax.so void RajErrorSink_bg::DoWrite+9() 
librax.so int RajErrorSink_Backend::run+0x128()
libmtcpp.so void*startThread+0x1e()
libc.so.1 _thr_setup+0x5b()
libc.so.1 _lwp_start()`
```

Code snippet

```
//
    std::deque<char*> _queue;

//
    void RajHistory_Backend::addMessage(char *msg)
    {
      _mutex.lock();
      _queue.push_front(msg);

      while ( _queue.size()-1 > _size )
      {
        char *b = _queue.back();
        _queue.pop_back();
        delete [] b;
      }
      _mutex.unlock();
    }
```

I'm actually struggling to find the crash reason as I'm new to mdb . I did some debugging using this [link](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fd3s.mff.cuni.cz%2Fteaching%2Fcrash_dump_analysis%2Fslides%2F06-mdb.pdf&ei=Y1zLVOGHGozl8AW8jIDoBA&usg=AFQjCNHyWejo9kS7fMNTODPMVujcvZMAVA&sig2=QU_BQYFp7_873u7kkPFDZQ&bvm=bv.84607526,d.dGc)

When I tried to print the variables in this method

```
> history_size/d
 libenv.so`history_size:
 libenv.so`history_size:         20

>msg/C
libc.so.1`msg:
libc.so.1`msg:  H

>msg/s
libc.so.1`msg:
libc.so.1`msg:  HGHcöHc°HÐÃUHåLeàLmèIüLuðH]ØAõL}øHì0
öIÖ|u5M
ötA>`
```

Does this mean the received message, `char* msg` is invalid?
How do I get the exact line in addMessage() method which caused the problem? Any hints on this how I can debug in mdb?

Comment: Time to start using `std::string` and drop the `char *` stuff.

Comment: Have you ensured that everything you put into the queue was allocated with `new []` and is owned by the queue?

Comment: PaulMcKenzie: ya I use std::string in my new codes. But this is quite an old module.
@molbdnilo: how do you ensure the messages put in the queue are owned by it?

Answer (score 0):

When mdb prints msg as *libc.so.1`msg* it’s indicating it found a value in libc, not in your code.  Similarly, it’s showing *libenv.so`history_size* so found a similarly named entry in libenv. mdb won’t know the names of arguments to your functions.

You’ll have a much easier time if you build your binaries with debugging info (`-g` flag to the compiler) and use the source level debugger for your compiler (gdb if you're using gcc, dbx if you're using the Sun Studio or Solaris Studio compilers).